# Issuing Intent to call activity along with parameters

Tags: android

I'm trying to send parameters string through putExtra function to the activity from the service, I have this code for my `Server.java`:

```
package com.winacro.andRHOME;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Server extends Service{

    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

        @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public Server getServerInstance() {
            return Server.this;
        }
    }

    public void switchSpeaker(int hr, int min){

        Toast.makeText(Server.this, hr +" , " +min, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String sendMessage = "1";

       /* Intent myIntent = new Intent(Server.this, andRHOME.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("sendMessage","1");
        startActivity(myIntent);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(Server.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager almmgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
        int min1 = cldr.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        cldr.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cldr.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
        almmgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cldr.getTimeInMillis(), pi);*/
    }

}
```

And This is the code for the Activity of whose `sendMessage()` method I want to access or pass in string variables too but My app is getting crashed, kindly help here!

```
package com.winacro.andRHOME;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

/**
 * This is the main Activity that displays the current chat session.
 */
public class andRHOME extends Activity {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "andRHOME";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Message types sent from the BluetoothChatService Handler
    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

    // Key names received from the BluetoothChatService Handler
    public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";

    // Intent request codes
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;
     String inp;

    // Layout Views
    private TextView mTitle;
    //private ListView mConversationView;
    //private EditText mOutEditText;
    //private Button mSendButton;
    private ToggleButton TB1;
    private ToggleButton TB2;
    private ToggleButton TB3;
    private ToggleButton TB4;
    // Name of the connected device
    private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
    // Array adapter for the conversation thread
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
    // String buffer for outgoing messages

    public StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
    // Local Bluetooth adapter
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    // Member object for the chat services
    public BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

        // Set up the window layout
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
        // Set up the custom title
        mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_left_text);
        mTitle.setText(R.string.app_name);
        mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_right_text);

        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        inp = bundle.getString("sendMessage");
        sendMessage(inp); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        // Otherwise, setup the chat session
        } else {
            if (mChatService == null) setupChat();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");

        // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
        // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
        // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
        if (mChatService != null) {
            // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
            if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
              // Start the Bluetooth chat services
              mChatService.start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupChat() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

        // Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread
        mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message);
        //mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);
       // mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);

        // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
        //mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
       // mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);

        // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
        //mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        /*mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
                //TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
                String message = "0";
                sendMessage(message);
            }
        });*/

        TB1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        TB1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (TB1.isChecked()){
                    String message = "1";
                    sendMessage(message);
                } else if (!TB1.isChecked()){
                    String message = "6";
                    sendMessage(message);
                }
            }
        });
        TB2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);
        TB2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (TB2.isChecked()){
                    String message = "0";
                    sendMessage(message);
                } else if (!TB2.isChecked()){
                    String message = "5";
                    sendMessage(message);
                }
            }
        });
        TB3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton02);
        TB3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (TB3.isChecked()){
                    String message = "2";
                    sendMessage(message);
                } else if (!TB3.isChecked()){
                    String message = "7";
                    sendMessage(message);
                }
            }
        });
        TB4 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton03);
        TB4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (TB4.isChecked()){
                    String message = "3";
                    sendMessage(message);
                } else if (!TB4.isChecked()){
                    String message = "8";
                    sendMessage(message);
                }
            }
        });
        // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
        mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(this, mHandler);

        // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
        mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
        if (mChatService != null) mChatService.stop();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
    }

    private void ensureDiscoverable() {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "ensure discoverable");
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
            BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends a message.
     * @param message  A string of text to send.
     */
    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
        if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Check that there's actually something to send
        if (message.length() > 0) {
            // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
            byte[] send = message.getBytes();
            mChatService.write(send);

            // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
            mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
            //mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
        }
    }

    // The action listener for the EditText widget, to listen for the return key
    private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener =
        new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                String message = view.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(message);
            }
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "END onEditorAction");
            return true;
        }
    };

    // The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                    mTitle.append(mConnectedDeviceName);
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connecting);
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                    mTitle.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                               + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data, true);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data, false);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
                setupChat();
            } else {
                // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occured
                Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void connectDevice(Intent data, boolean secure) {
        // Get the device MAC address
        String address = data.getExtras()
            .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        // Attempt to connect to the device
        mChatService.connect(device, secure);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent serverIntent = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.scan:
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE);
            return true;
        case R.id.timer:
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.winacro.andRHOME.Timer");
            startActivity(myIntent);
            return true;
        /*case R.id.discoverable:
            // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
            ensureDiscoverable();
            return true;*/
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apps and code crash all the time here. A LogCat output would help us figure out where it's crashing.

Comment: Yes this is true but the problem is I have restarted the ADB server and done all such sort of things but I wasn't able to get the logcat,

Comment: But If you can just show me a way to send parameters in putExtra from my service to a activity then It would be more than enough!

Comment: The code you've commented out looks just fine. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidWasser I think there is some problem in Activity even I was thinking that the problem is in putting the intent handler at the right place though i putted it under the onCreate(Bundle INstance..) only

Comment: Don't know how to attache so here is the link of the file >> http://winacro.com/AndroidLOGCAT/logcat.txt

Comment: I have  no mediaplayer etc in my app anywhere even then there is some exception which states it! strange!

Comment: You have a NullPointerException in onCreate() on line 117 of your file. Which line is that? Maybe one of your `findViewById()` calls is returning null?

Comment: Regarding the media player, the logcat contains all logs from all applications on your phone. You have a mediaplayer application that is making a lot of noise in there.

Comment: @DavidWasser , So what I can I do with that onCreate() as it works fine atleast when these intent calls aren't made to the handler of the intent in the Aciivity

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What works fine? Your activity crashes in `onCreate()`. That isn't working fine. Which is line 117 in your file?

Comment: I mean't that whether in the acitivity I can put the intent handler for server intent in onStart if its crashing in onCreate() , also please have a look on my placing of intent handler under the onCreate() is it just fine?

Comment: crash was there even when i commented out intent stuff from activity & service

Comment: Crash not there now atleast app is starting ,THIS was the culprit >>      //Toast.makeText(Server.this, hr +" , " +min, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); it was in service